# Implement special metaclass. Nonify field in inherited class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, field, metaclass

I have a task:

> Implement metaclass "ModelCreator", that allows to declare class
>   fields in the following form:
>
> ```
> class Student(object):  
>     __metaclass__ = ModelCreator  
>     name = StringField()
> ```
>
> Where `StringField` - some object that indicates, that this field is
>   text field.   So there must be a class, whose constructor receives
>   named argument "name" and stores it in corresponding attribute (with
>   type check and cast)
>
> So you can type something like this:
>
> ```
> s = Student(name = 'abc')  
> print s.name
> ```
>
> The class should allow inheritance and should verify the types such
>   way, that you cannot write a number to text field.

This my implementation but there is problem with inherited class it's "name" field is not empty(as I expect it to be) it recieves name value from previous classes.

```
class StringField(object):
    def __init__(self, my_type, default=None):
        self.type = my_type
        self.name = None
        if default:
            self.default = default
        else:
            self.default = my_type()

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, self.type):
            setattr(instance, self.name, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError("value must be type of {}".format(self.type))

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.name, self.default)

    def __del__(self):
        raise AttributeError("you can`t remove this attribute {}".format(self.name))


class ModelCreator(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, diction):
        socket = []
        for key, value in diction.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, StringField):
                value.name = "_{}".format(key)
                socket.append(value.name)

        def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            for names in kwargs:
                if '_{}'.format(names) in diction['__slots__']:
                    if isinstance(kwargs[names], diction[names].type):
                        diction[names].default = kwargs[names]
                    else:
                        raise TypeError('attr has other type')
            return type(name, bases, diction)

        diction["__slots__"] = socket
        diction["__new__"] = new
        return super(ModelCreator, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, diction)


class Student(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModelCreator
    name = StringField(str)


class School(Student):
    second_name = StringField(str)


def main():
       st = Student(name = "Hello")
       print st.name
       st.name = "Vlad"
       sc = School(second_name = "World")
       print sc.second_name, sc.name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code prints

> Hello
>   World Hello

But it should (by task) print

> Hello
>   World None

The questions are:

> Why the type(st) returns " type 'type' "? (I thought it is instance not a class)
>   Why the type(sc) returns " class '**main**.ModelCreator' "?
>
> How to Nonify the value of "name" field in the "Student" class, so it will only be saved in "st" (cause it is now somehow contained even in "sc")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a bit convoluted - but it is doing nothing les than what you told it to do.

And what it does, besides the needed descriptor (i.e.: the class containing the  `__get__` and `__set__` methods) and usual metaclass mechanisms is plugging in a `__new__` method to the class that is wrong in several ways.

For one, the `new` method that is assigned to the class `__new__` ends its executing by using a hardcoded call to `type.` - that is the most wrong thing of all - as type returns a new class - not an instance. The call at the end of the plugged `new` method should be to `object.__new__` - or better yet, using  a mechanism that would call the `__new__` in the next class on its `__mro__`  (but that would not that be trivial - as you will have to find that in the metaclass `__new__` code surrounding the `new` method you are plugging in).

Anyway - it only would make sense to call `type` there if you would want classes that use this metaclass to be themselves "class factories" - that would return whole new classes not only with the declared fields, but with the sent-in defaults.  And calling type is why you are seeing `type(st)` returning `type`- which is your first question.

Then, it is still wrong:  the `new` class method, which is called at each instantation, sets the default attribute to the descritor (i.e. "field") - and that default will apply to every other instantiation of the same class - or other classes that inherit from it. You should set the default, if any, on the call to your `StringField` class  - and on the method that will become the `__new__` on the class, set the value for the instance.

That can be done if you first call the superclass `__new__` to obtain an actual instance, and then loop though the passed in keyword arguments, and use `setattr` as the mechanism to set the attribute. Using setattr will ensure the StringField `__set__` method is properly called.

So, there are many things weird in this code, but an attempt to fix it go by re-writting your metaclass `__new__` to be more or less:

```
 def __new__(mcs, name, bases, diction):
    socket = set()
    # mechanism to inherit classes that make use of sockets:
    for base in bases:
        if hasattr(base, '__slots__'):
            socket.update(base.__slots__)
    for key, value in diction.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, StringField):
            value.name = "_{}".format(key)
            socket.add(value.name)


    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # A working __new__ mechanism that respects inheritance.
        for supercls in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            if  '__new__' in supercls.__dict__:
                # don't pass args and kwargs up.
                # unless really there is distinct mechanism
                # to use args and kwargs than the StringField
                # class.
                # otherwise this would break any `__init__`
                # method you put in your classes.
                instance = supercls.__new__(cls)
                break  # the last class in __mro__ is object which always has '__new__'

        for names in kwargs:
            if '_{}'.format(names) in cls.__slots__:
                # no need to typecheck here. StringField's __set__ does that
                setattr(instance, kwargs[names])
        return instance

    diction["__slots__"] = list(socket)
    diction["__new__"] = __new__
    return super(ModelCreator, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, diction)
```

That said, you should not really waste your time in studying such advanced mechanisms in Python 2.7 at this point (2017) - Python 2 last release was in 2010, and it will be out of maintenance in 2020 - these mechanisms have improved and got a lot better in the 3.x series. In Python 3.6, with the `__set_name__` descriptor functionality and new `__init_subclass__` mechanism you would not even need to use a custom metaclass for the intended results you have here.